# How to print data from a few arrays

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a few arrays like this but much bigger:

```
let katakana = ["フシギダネ","フシギソウ","フシギバナ"]
let romadzi = ["Fushigidane","Fushigisou","Fushigibana"]
let number = ["001","002","003"]
```

And I want to print in one line all data from every array with similar index:

```
print("Hi im \(katakana[0]), or \(romadzi[0]) and my nymber is \(number[0])")
print("Hi im \(katakana[1]), or \(romadzi[1]) and my nymber is \(number[1])")
```

How to do that with my huge arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
katakana.indices.forEach {
    print("Hi im \(katakana[$0]), or \(romadzi[$0]) and my nymber is \(number[$0])")
}
```

Given that all arrays are of same size

Answer (score 2):

A more efficient and reliable way is to create a custom struct. Each instance contains *all* information about *one* person.

The `description` property provides to get the description string with `array[i]`

```
struct Person : CustomStringConvertible {
    let katakana, romadzi, number : String
    
    var description : String {
        return "Hi I'm \(katakana), or \(romadzi) and my number is \(number)"
    }
}

let people = [Person(katakana: "フシギダネ", romadzi: "Fushigidane", number: "001"),
              Person(katakana: "フシギソウ", romadzi: "Fushigisou", number: "002"),
              Person(katakana: "フシギバナ", romadzi: "Fushigibana", number: "003")]


print(people[1]) // Hi I'm フシギソウ, or Fushigisou and my number is 002
```

and to print all

```
people.forEach{print($0)}
```

Comment: i already have a struct, but my question was about how to create people array because my arrays more than 700 words

Answer (score 0):

```
   let katakana = ["フシギダネ","フシギソウ","フシギバナ"]
   let romadzi = ["Fushigidane","Fushigisou","Fushigibana"]
   let number = ["001","002","003"]
    
    for i in 0..<katakana.count
    {
        print("Hi im \(katakana[i]), or \(romadzi[i]) and my nymber is \(number[i])")
    }
```